# EADDRNOTAVAIL while using EC2 instance only

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

[image]

[image]

My node application is listening to port 8080. When I add

```
app.listen(port,'50.30.217.289');
```

I can access the application from the browser. But when I replace the IP address with the Elastic IP address of my EC2 instance, I get an error :

EADDRNOTAVAIL

How do I fix this ?

Comment: I wrote a blog post on one way to set up `nginx` to make a development server available from an EC2 instance: http://www.bitsumma.com/2018/11/07/running-production-and-deployment-react-apps-on-the-same-ec2-host/

Answer (score 8):

What you are trying to do is not how it works in EC2.

> The public IP address is mapped to the primary private IP address through network address translation (NAT).
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

If you examine your network interfaces on the machine, you won't find any public IP addresses on them.  The public IP addresses are translated onto the private addresses at the Internet gateway.  This is done automatically with no configuration needed, for instances with public IP addresses.

To bind a service to a specific public address, you bind it to the matching *private* IP address on the instance itself.

Comment: So it means that my node server on the ec2 instance must run on the private IP address while other browsers on the internet must be able to access the instance using the elastic IP address right ?

Comment: I am sorry, but i am still not clear on how to solve this issue.

Comment: To your question: yes, exactly.  Bind to the private address.

Comment: That does not help either. It only makes the app run on the VM but still does not let public access to it. My issue is with the public resolution. Also, later when I tried to ssh to the server, the connection times out.

Comment: That is how it is done in EC2.  If it is not working, you have an issue with security group settings, or you are not using a public IP that is actually associated with your instance, or you are using multiple public IPs on the same instance, and you do not have something like policy routing configured correctly.

Comment: The security group I created and linked with this has inbound traffic permissions for HTTP, SSH, RDP, HTTPS and a custom rule for port 8080. I also added a general rule for all traffic on all ports from all sources.

Answer (score 4):

`EADDRNOTAVAIL` means your EC2 instance does not have a network interface that has that IP address assigned, so you cannot start listening on it.

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot. I do have a network interface linked with the elastic IP address listed as public IP address.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show that particular IP address. Either way, you should double check with something like `ifconfig` on the actual server to be extra sure.

Comment: i added more screenshots. The Network interface and the elastic Ip address are linked. Also, the result for ipconfig on the server. I have a lot of time on this and would appreciate all the help. thanks

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong IP address still. In your original code you posted you are trying to use '50.30.212.245' but in your screenshots you are showing '52.27.160.173'.

Comment: 50.30.212.245 is the IP adress of the machine I am using.. 52.27.160.173 is the ec2 instance IP address. I want it to get working for my ec2 instance. I get the above error for the ec2 IP address

Comment: Ah ok I misread your question. So you're sure '52.27.160.173' appears in your ipconfig output? Your screenshot only shows the private IP and an IPv6 address.

Comment: No. The '52.27.160.173' does not appear in the result. The screenshot shows all of the ipconfig output. So the public IP is not set then ?

Comment: Correct. You need to assign the 52.* IP to an interface if you want to start listening on that address.