# frontend (React) call backend (express) fails to bind to HOST environment variable when trying to Dockerize

Tags: node.js, docker, express, dockerfile, create-react-app

I am trying to dockerize both a frontend made with create-react-app and its express API backend.

The docker containers sit on ec2 instances. I have tried several tutorials and also threads here on stackoverflow, but I can't work out what is going wrong.

The error I get is:

```
Could not find an open port at ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

this refers to my .env file which contains only

```
HOST= ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

my Dockerfile for the front end is as follows:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

whereas the backend's:

```
FROM node:12-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["node", "app.js" ]
```

I need the backend to run on port 3001 and the frontend to run on 3000. The frontend is bound to the backend api via the proxy line in package.json, where I have placed:

```
"proxy":"http://ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001",
```

Both containers build fine. However, running the backend with `docker run -p 3001:3001 server` and then `docker run -p 3000:3000 client` spits the error

```
Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
Learn more here: https://xxx.xx/xxx-advanced-config

Could not find an open port at ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Network error message: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 10.xx.0.xxx
```

I have tried running only the server side and then running npm start from my local machine, it works. The problem seems to have to do with docker networking between containers.

I also tried running the server side with the command

```
docker run -p 10.xx.0.xxx:3000:3000 client
```

to make sure the client pings the right ip address, however this didn't work.

Could anyone give me some direction please?

If you need more info on the source code, please just leave a comment, I didn't want to clutter the thread by making it longer than it already is..

Thank you

Comment: See if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711564/eaddrnotavail-while-using-ec2-instance-only